# How do I use a datatype-based SQL Stored Procedure when using Visual Basic 6?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm adding features to an old VB6 application. We're making it more geo-spatial friendly. I've completed the database-end changes by upgrading to SQL Server 2012 Express and am trying to use the **geography** datatype.

In VB6, I have a piece of code that looks like this (and yes, I know Latitude is spelled wrong):

```
rsGeoref![Lattitude] = IIf(dblLatitude <> "", Val(dblLatitude), Null)
rsGeoref![LatDirection] = IIf(strLatDirection = "", Null, strLatDirection)
rsGeoref![LatDegrees] = IIf(dblLatDegrees <> "", Val(dblLatDegrees), Null)
```

This is modifying a RecordSet that is then pushed back to the Database later on using:

```
rsGeoref.Update
```

So I now have a field called GeogSpatial that uses the **geography** datatype from SQL Server 2012. I want to update it the same way. This doesn't work:

```
rsGeoref![GeogSpatial] = "geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(" + CStr(dblSignedLong) + " " + CStr(dblSignedLat) + ")', 4326)"
```

I believe the error comes from using the SQL stored procedure **geography::STGeomFromText**. If so, is there a better way for me to do this without having to re-write the entire section as a monolithic SQL query?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The DLL builds fine, without errors. The application only produces a custom error window with no contents. The program does not crash, it simply fails to update the database. I'm going to keep digging. After the `rsGeoref.Update`, there is another convoluted function call that basically shakes out to `rsGeoref.UpdateBatch adAffectAll`. I'm not sure which of those two calls is causing the error to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain you can set the value of a field in a recordset to a string literal that represents a call to a SQL stored procedure/function and have that execute as SQL code.  What it will attempt to do is just set that field to the string literal and most likely you will get a type mismatch error at runtime if the string can not be cast to the type of the field.

I tested this theory with an equivalent setup, but using a call to GetDate() assigned to a datetime field instead of STGeomFromText.  This failed as I imagined since the text 'GetDate()' cannot be assigned to a datetime.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. In Java, which I'm more comfortable with, the JDBC has an escape syntax that allows for creating queries that include function calls. 

So I'm going to try to write ``rsGeoref![GeogSpatial] = "{ fn geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(" + CStr(dblSignedLong) + " " + CStr(dblSignedLat) + ")', 4326)}"``. But it's a four hour build process. So I probably won't see results on that until tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, good luck.  The only way I was able to get it to work was to write a separate command statement to just update the geometry field and in that statement call the SQL function STGeomFromText.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I'm not the most comfortable with VB. I'll give a heads up if plan A works, but I'm probably going to have to do what you did and push a second statement after the RecordSet has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for the assist again. As an update: I was forced to use an ADODB.Command object pushed out after the recordset had been updated back to the DB. The ``{fn }`` syntax didn't work in the case of modifying the RecordSet directly (because the stored procedures are not stored in the RecordSet, but rather the database itself.)